# How can I make a sink drain slowly on purpose?

Tags: plumbing

I'm sure this is an odd question, but here it goes. One of my kids is currently obsessed with plumbing, and wants the sink to drain slowly.

Our drains, as for as I know, are pretty typical, and have white plastic p-traps.

Is there anything that I can buy and connect to the drain, either before or after the p-trap, to intentionally make the sink drain slowly? Even better if there's a way "turn it off" without taking the part back off.

I know there are shut off values, but those all seem to be for intakes, not for drains. And those, as I understand it, use different sized pipes, and you can't typically mix and match parts between them.

And of course, normally it's a really bad idea to "close" or partly close your drain, since that is past where the overflow connects. But I would rather have a safe and reversible way to "clog" the drain, rather than finding out later that the drain was intentionally clogged by my son with whatever was on hand at the time.

Comment: Something simple like small flat dish(cup holder/saucer) will stop/slow down draining.  Can also be moved a bit to speed up/slow down draining.  A glass type will let them see the water draining.  Kid sounds like me, weird.

Comment: Kid sounds like a kid - interested in the world around her.

Comment: Partially closing the stopper that's typically installed on most drains seems like the easy and obvious choice, is that not an option?

Comment: Come over to my house and pull the gunk out of the drain I have that's running slow. Win for both of us!

Comment: There probably are youtube vids showing how plumbing works, some should also have clear/transparent pipes.  Plumbers also make good money.

Comment: Depending on age/maturity, I’d encourage you to figure out a slow drain with a perfectly functional overflow. The idea of adjusting the rod on the stopper makes sense if you have that kind of stopper.

Comment: @crip659 My kid wants the drain clogged. Even better if it makes a gurgling sound.  I think we've done something like what you're suggesting already. But I might try it again. Oh, and he's been watching a lot of plumbing videos on YouTube! We don't have any clear pipes though, I should look into that!

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Most of our sinks have this style https://www.lowes.com/pd/Keeney-Chrome-Bathroom-Decorative-Sink-Drain/3133211 "Pop up assembly with plastic body and polished chrome top. Complete with lift rod plunger and linkage."

I don't think just putting in the plug is going to keep him happy for long. Or are you and AloysiusDefenestrate suggesting something more creative with the stopper?

Comment: @Tim That stopper need not be completely open or completely shut, you can pull the lift arm partway up to close the drain partway. Or, re-seat the pop-up arm lever where it attaches to the stopper so that the drain is partly closed when the pop-up is all the way down. I've definitely reinstalled the arm lever in the wrong hole before, which made it impossible to open the stopper all the way and caused slow draining.

Comment: Oh, and thanks everyone for such a positive response to my question!

Comment: I would suggest making a cheap drainage system to experiment on instead of the house plumbing.  As long as no nasty stuff is put down, can have the system drain into a big enough bucket/container.  Just need a cheap vent going up, a few feet of main drain and some connecting pipes from a cheap sink/tub.  Have him build it.

Comment: Or maybe leave the sink alone entirely: https://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project-ideas/Geo_p049/geology/model-water-flow-rivers

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anything that I can buy and connect to the drain, either
> before or after the p-trap, to intentionally make the sink drain
> slowly?

You can buy PVC ball valves in the same size as your sink drain.  Just use the search term "pvc ball valve" in your favorite search engine.  You will need to do some fitting research, and your local big box store may not carry a 1-1/4" or 1-1/2" PVC glue ball valve.  You'll also most likely need to do a little bit of destructive plumbing, but the valve itself won't cause any damage long term to the drain, it'll just be... weird.  It can always be removed later as well.

If you put it on the p-trap itself it will be easier to remove later, but where it is easiest to insert it will depend on what's below your sink and what options are available to you to buy.

PVC sizes are PVC sizes, no matter the pipe's purpose or thickness.  The listed size is always the outside diameter of the pipe, and the internal diameter is determined by the wall thickness.  There's no difference between supply and waste PVC in terms of compatibility other than that the box store is unlikely to carry parts for supplies as big as typical waste lines.

If you want to get really fancy, you could re-plumb the sink with glass piping, so that kiddo can see what's going on...

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-1-4-in-PVC-Threaded-Ball-Valve-PVCBV114F/319717649

How would you connect it though? If I compare that to  a p-trap that looks like mine, let's say this one https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-1-1-4-in-White-Plastic-Sink-Drain-P-Trap-HDC9700B/316622140 it looks like threads are different (inside vs outside), and it's made of polypropylene so I'm guessing the normal PVC solvent welding is out of the question.

I get the impression that these are designed to make it really hard to accidentally mix and match them.

Comment: To at least partly answer my question in my last comment, some googling suggests there's something that's called a "Marvel Adapter" that would work. I see some bundled with p-traps.

Comment: you can use furnco connectors.  just solvent in some male pieces to the 1.25 pvc ball valve and then furnco on both ends of the cut poly.  to remove just use 1 furnco to reconnect

Comment: Tubular products used for waste, such as tailpieces, tubular P-traps, and other slip-joint fittings are specifically different in the way they are sized compared to PVC piping. They are not compatible *at all* as it applies to glue connection. Tube is sized by *actual* O.D. (e.g. 1 1/2", 1 1/4") whereas pipe is sized by *nominal* I.D. The only thing that is the same between the two product types is the thread that is used. The statement that "PVC sizes are PVC sizes, no matter the pipe's purpose..." is incorrect; unfortunately it is not that simple.